# OnTriggerEnter2D not working Unity3d (JavaScript)

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, unityscript

Dear sctackoverflow Community,

I've got a problem with the onTriggerEnter2D function in unity3D, since it's not working, and at the same time, I'm not aware of what is going wrong.
**Note that I have searched this problem in other forums and threads, and none of the solutions would work for me.**

So, basically what I've got is two 2D-objects (sprites) and both of them got aswell a rigidbody2D as a circle collider 2D. I have *'is Trigger'* **checked** on both of them, and I've got *'is Kinematic'* **unchecked** in both 2D rigidbodys.
Also I've tried all sorts of possible combinations, testing around with the colliders and rigidbodys.

Now my code is this (JavaScript):

```
    #pragma strict


var velocity : Vector2;
var objectInReach : boolean = false;

function Update () {

transform.position = transform.position + (velocity * Time.deltaTime);


}

function onTriggerEnter2D(other: Collider2D)
{
    objectInReach = true;
    Debug.Log(objectInReach);
    Debug.Log("collision!");

    if(other.gameObject.tag == "player" || other.gameObject.tag == "buttonSprite")
    {
        Debug.Log("collision!");
        Debug.Log(objectInReach);
    }

}
```

*(My moving object is tagged "player", and my static object is tagged "buttonSprite")
(The script is attached to the moving sprite, tagged "player")*

You can see that by now I'm desperately trying multiple things out in my code.

Please, if you know what I'm doing wrongly, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your Typing.... Change `onTriggerEnter2D` to `OnTriggerEnter2D`

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I oversaw that. Finally solved my problem, haha